# How do I make my laptop hold right click when I right click with two fingers and drag it around

Tags: keyboard

I have had this problem for some while, and in some games that require you to right click and move your mouse (in this case my touch pad) it doesn't work, the only semi-solution I found was to left click in the bottom right corner of the touch pad then drag from there, however this is not a good solution, and it handicaps me in a lot of ways, is there a way to make it so when right clicking, dragging will hold right click?

Comment: Isn't a "left click in the bottom right corner of the touch pad" a right click?

Comment: yes, but it is not very convenient to have to go to the bottom right corner every time and it limits how much i can turn right

Comment: I TOTALLY get it.. I thought the statement was funny.  I simply can't game with a touchpad for this reason.  Sorry.. I have no solution.

Comment: oof, better have a mouse ig

Comment: Unless the TouchPad drivers offer this function you are out of luck.